# How to predict months/time using neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Assume I have a problem where I have to predict time let it be years, months or days. So I think it's a regression problem but the problem is how to do it. I mean usually dense layers prediction will be in floating number right? But months or days are usually interger.

That is we can predict 8.65 months when the y_true is 8 months right? How do deal with this? Should I just round it?

What type of loss function can I use in this case?

Comment: How are those time distributed in your train sample ?

Comment: @lcrmorin I didn't get what you meant here. Basically In my use case I have to some X_train it has to predict months (i.e 1, 2 or 6 etc..) which is my y_train. But my question is regression models is continuous isn't it. So should I just round my prediction?

Comment: Yeah, in the end you may need to specify a way to end up with an integer, mainly by either rounding or using a method that output integer; But the first question here is what the distribution of those time looks like. It will basically help you choose a method and a basis for choosing at what time step you want to work.

Comment: @lcrmorin The distribution is some what right skewed. The months start from 1 and end in around 500 months or so. You've mentioned that there are method that output integer. Can you explain a bit regarding this please? How can I achieve this in my case?